# Replacing strings with special characters in command line sed

Tags: linux, replace, command-line, sed, special-characters

I want to uncomment a line of a config file by replacing the line `%% {some_string, []},` with `{some_string, []}` in the command line.

I have tried a few different formats using `sed`:

`sed 's/%% {some_string, []},/{some_string, []}/' filename`

`sed "s/%% {some_string, []},/{some_string, []}/" filename`

`sed "s/'%% {some_string, []},'/'{some_string, []}'/" filename`

`sed 's/"%% {some_string, []},"/"{some_string, []}"/' filename`

but every time have received the output `sed: -e expression #1, char (some number): unterminated s' command`

I am assuming it's something to do with my formatting because of my special characters, but can't seem to find any other posts with the same characters that could be causing the issue. I also cannot declare these strings as variables beforehand as I need this to run in the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` requires you to escape the square brackets.

```
sed 's/%% {some_string, \[\]},/{some_string, []}/' filename
```

Comment: Strictly, only the `[` needs to be escaped; the `]` only has a special meaning after an unescaped `[`.  But it is clearer to escape both.